# IllegalArgumentException: Object is not of type class org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource

Tags: gradle, jetty, illegalargumentexception

Trying to build a hello world application using Jetty 9.1.4 + Gradle.
My project strucutre

- [project-root-dir]

  - - [gradle]
  - - - [jetty-9.1.4]
  - - - - [lib]
  - - - - jetty-jndi-9.1.4.v(...).jar
  - - - - jetty-plus-9.1.4.v(...)/jar
  - - [src]
  - - - [main]
  - - - - [java]
  - - - - - [servlet]
  - - - - - - HelloWorldServlet.java
  - - - - [webapp]
  - - - - - [WEB-INF]
  - - - - - - jetty-env.xml
  - - - - - - web.xml
  - - build.gralde

My web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <servlet>
        <display-name>HelloWorldServlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>servlet.HelloWorldServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

My jetty-env.xml

```
<New id="DSTest" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource">
    <Arg></Arg>
    <Arg>jdbc/DSTest</Arg>
    <Arg>
        <New class="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource">
            <Set name="Url">jdbc:mysql://sql2.freemysqlhosting.net/sql238625</Set>
            <Set name="User">sql238625</Set>
            <Set name="Password">gD5%tN5!</Set>
        </New>
    </Arg>
</New>
```

My build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'jetty'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    providedCompile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.30'
    runtime 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.1.2'
    providedCompile fileTree(dir: 'jetty-9.1.4/lib', include: '*.jar')
}

httpPort = 8080
stopPort = 9451
stopKey = 'foo'
```

When I executing gradle jettyRunWar task I'm getting this exception with stacktrace:

```
Failed startup of context org.gradle.api.plugins.jetty.internal.JettyPluginWebAppContext@12cb504{/recipe-beagle,D:\Dev\projects\recipe-beagle\build\libs\recipe-beagle.war}
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object is not of type class org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Resource
    at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:189)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration.configureWebApp(EnvConfiguration.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1269)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:489)
    at org.gradle.api.plugins.jetty.internal.JettyPluginWebAppContext.doStart(JettyPluginWebAppContext.java:112)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.plugins.jetty.internal.Jetty6PluginServer.start(Jetty6PluginServer.java:111)
    at org.gradle.api.plugins.jetty.AbstractJettyRunTask.startJettyInternal(AbstractJettyRunTask.java:240)[...]
```

So, what could be the reason and how to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

The reason was in running jettyRunWar gradle task. Gradle jetty plugin uses 6.xxx version of jetty server, and it's packeges are org.mortbay.*** and they are not fit to new (jetty-9.1.4) org.eclipse.jetty.***.
The solution is not to ise gradle plugin task, but to make war with gradle 'war' task, put by hands this war to local jetty_installation_directory/webapps and then run jetty in jetty_installation_directory with command java -jar start.jar.

To make thing go right, build.gradle must look like:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    providedCompile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.30'
    runtime 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.1.2'
}

task copyFilesToJetty(type : Copy) {
    from 'build/libs'
    into 'jetty-9.1.4/webapps'
    include '*.war'
}
```